# Merge rows with same user with different currencies which is dynamically generated using codeigniter and mysql

Tags: mysql, css, html, codeigniter

Using group by currency id i list all the users with their amount.Now the same users display in multiple line. I need to display in same row.

My sql query from model class

```
SELECT pay_date, 
       sub_ins_name                                      AS name, 
       Sum(iman_sub_product_payment_details.amtreceived) AS amount, 
       Sum(iman_sub_product_payment_details.refundedamt) AS refamount, 
       iman_sub_product_payment_details.subscriber_id    AS subid, 
       iman_sub_product_payment_details.cur_id           AS cur_id 
FROM   iman_subscriber_insitution_details 
       LEFT JOIN `iman_sub_product_payment_details` 
              ON 
`iman_sub_product_payment_details`.`subscriber_id` = `iman_subscriber_insitution_details`.`sub_institute_id`
WHERE  iman_sub_product_payment_details.pay_date >= Date("2016-01-01") 
       AND iman_sub_product_payment_details.pay_date <= Date("2016-08-01") 
GROUP  BY iman_subscriber_insitution_details.sub_institute_id, 
          iman_sub_product_payment_details.cur_id 
UNION 
SELECT pay_date, 
       agentname                                         AS name, 
       Sum(iman_sub_product_payment_details.amtreceived) AS amount, 
       Sum(iman_sub_product_payment_details.refundedamt) AS refamount, 
       iman_sub_product_payment_details.subscriber_id    AS subid, 
       iman_sub_product_payment_details.cur_id           AS cur_id 
FROM   iman_agent_details 
       LEFT JOIN `iman_sub_product_payment_details` 
              ON `iman_sub_product_payment_details`.`dealer_id` = 
                 `iman_agent_details`.`agentid` 
WHERE  iman_sub_product_payment_details.pay_date >= Date("2016-01-01") 
       AND iman_sub_product_payment_details.pay_date <= Date("2016-08-01") 
GROUP  BY iman_agent_details.agentid, 
          iman_sub_product_payment_details.cur_id 
UNION 
SELECT pay_date, 
       resname                                        AS name, 
       Sum(iman_resource_payment_details.rec_amt)     AS amount, 
       Sum(iman_resource_payment_details.refundedamt) AS refamount, 
       iman_resource_payment_details.status           AS subid, 
       iman_resource_payment_details.curid            AS cur_id 
FROM   iman_other_resources 
       LEFT JOIN iman_resource_payment_details 
              ON `iman_resource_payment_details`.`resourceid` = 
                 iman_other_resources.`id` 
WHERE  iman_resource_payment_details.pay_date >= Date("2016-01-01") 
       AND iman_resource_payment_details.pay_date <= Date("2016-08-01") 
GROUP  BY iman_other_resources.id, 
          iman_resource_payment_details.curid 
ORDER  BY name ASC
```

view Page

```
<table class="table table-hover tablesorter" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label>From Date</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" value="<?=$fromdate?>">
            </td>

            <th>
                <label>To Date</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" value="<?=$todate?>">
            </td>
            <th>
                <label>List By</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="sel_listby" name="sel_listby" id="sel_listby">
                    <option value="0">--Select---</option>
                    <option value="institution" <?php if ($listby=='institution' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Institution</option>
                    <option value="dealer" <?php if ($listby=='dealer' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Dealer</option>
                    <option value="or" <?php if ($listby=='or' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Other Resources</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label>From Amount</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="from_amount" id="from_amount" value="<?=$from_amount?>">
            </td>
            <th>
                <label>To Amount</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="to_amount" id="to_amount" value="<?=$to_amount?>">
            </td>
            <th>
                <label>Category</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="sel_category" name="sel_category" id="sel_category">
                    <option value="0">--Select---</option>
                    <?php foreach($subcategory as $val): ?>
                    <option value="<?=$val->subscriptionid ?>" <?php if ($val->subscriptionid==$subcat) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>
                        <?=$val->subscriptionname?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label>Currency</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="sel_cur" name="sel_cur" id="sel_cur" onchange="fncSubmit();">
                    <option value="0">--Select---</option>
                    <?php $i=0; foreach($cur as $val): ?>
                    <option value="<?=$val->priceid?>" <?php if ($val->priceid==$currency) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>
                        <?=$val->pricename?></option>
                    <?php $i++;endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <th>
                <label>Sort By</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="sel_sortby" name="sel_sortby" id="sel_sortby">
                    <option value="0">--Select---</option>
                    <option value="N" <?php if ($sortby=='N' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>New </option>
                    <option value="R" <?php if ($sortby=='R' ) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Renewal </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <th>
                <label>Combo</label>
            </th>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="txt_combo" id="txt_combo" value="1" maxlength="100" <?php echo $comboval==1 ? 'checked' : '';?> />

                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-success">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="9">
                <div id="dvData">
                    <div align="right">

                        <!--<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onClick="$('#tblExport').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>&nbsp; Export to Excel</a>-->
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport();"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>&nbsp; EXPORT to Excel </button>
                        <!--<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="fncExportExcel('<?=$modid?>','<?=$listby?>','<?=$fromdate?>','<?=$todate?>','<?=$prodtype?>','<?=$dealerid?>','<?=$comboval?>'); return false;">Export to excel</a>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="with_print">
                        <div><b><center> Subscription Report <?php if(!empty($listby)){ ?>for <?=$listby?><?php } ?> From <?=$fromdate?> To <?=$todate?></center></b>
                        </div>
                        <table border="0" width="100%" class="TFtable" id="tblExport" style="border:1px solid black; ">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>S.No</th>
                                    <th width="40%">
                                        <?php if ($listby=='dealer' ){ echo "Agent Name";}else if ($listby=='or' ){ echo "Other Resource Name";}else{?>Subscriber Name
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Source Name</th>
                                    <?php if($currency!=0){ ?>
                                    <th>Amount</th>
                                    <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <?php foreach($cur as $val){ ?>
                                    <th>
                                        <?=$val->pricename?></th>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php $i=1; foreach($query as $val){ ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <?=$i?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php if ($listby=='dealer' ){ echo $val->agentname;}else if($listby=='institution'){ echo $val->sub_ins_name;}else{?>
                                        <?=$val->name?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php if ($listby=='dealer' ){ echo "Agent";}else if ($listby=='or' ){ echo "Other Resouces";}else if($listby=='institution' ){ echo "Direct";}else{if($val->subid=="OR"){echo "Other Resouces";} else if($val->subid==0){echo "Agent";} else{echo "Direct";}} ?></td>
                                    <?php if($currency!=0){ ?>
                                    <td>
                                        <?=$val->amount-$val->refamount?></td>
                                    <?php }else {?>
                                    <?php foreach($cur as $value){ ?>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php if($value->priceid==$val->cur_id){echo $val->amount-$val->refamount; $curtot[$value->priceid]+=$val->amount-$val->refamount; }?>
                                    </td>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                </tr>
                                <?php $i++; $netamount+=$val->amount-$val->refamount; } //print_r($curtot); ?>

                                <tfoot>
                                    <?php if($currency==0){ ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td><b>Total</b>
                                        </td>

                                        <?php foreach($cur as $value){ ?>
                                        <td><b> <?=$curtot[$value->priceid]?> </b> </td>
                                        <?php $gt+=$curtot[$value->priceid];} ?>

                                    </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <tr id="footerExport">

                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <?php if($currency==0){ ?>
                                        <?php for($c=1;$c<count($cur);$c++){?>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <?php }} ?>
                                        <td><b>Grand Total</b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><b>
                                    <?php if($currency==0){ ?>
                                    <?=$gt?>
                                    <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <?=$netamount?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <button id="pdf" class="btn btn-danger">Print</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is my screenshot

[image]

C.S.pochen&sons Usd amount:350 displayed in one row
C.S.pochen&sons INR amount:7700 display in another row.

Can anybody help to merge this row.

Answer (score 0):

This question would be easier to answer with more information.

- Do you have access to the entire web application?
- Does this have to be done in css?
- What language is the application in?
- Share code involved with question.

Typically, it is a bad idea to put this kind of logic in the view.  What happens later if they change the database and all of a sudden it doesn't match the selector in your css?  In a database with thousands of entries, it would be easy for the database programmer to not notice they broke your css rule inadvertently, and the client could then be exporting tables with wrong values.

In your controller there should be a statement that selects table data and returns it to the view.  The logic for this should be done there.

Comment: No access. Because we enter live records, Html,css,codeigniter and mysql page. Contents display dynamically from db. I edited and added my code.

Comment: All the records are displayed from database. So i think no problem occurs. I set foreign key for all tables.